# Flyway: slow performance migrating a large number of scripts

Tags: java, oracle, flyway

We are using [flywayDB](https://flywaydb.org/) for some years to manage a quite large database application running on oracle 12c. This works fine and very reliable.

But recently we are running into performance problems during database migration. The number of database skripts we manage in our versions-table has risen beyond 10,000. The time flyway takes to migrate a single script has increased from some originally milliseconds to currently about a second. It seems that flyway per single migration step selects the full content of the versions table to calculate at client side its installation rank. This doesnt scale well.

Is there any possiblity to speed up flyway, may be by caching the content of the versions table?

We are using the Java-API of flyway version 3.2.1.

For completeness I have written a testcase to demonstrate this behaviour.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class PerformanceTestcase {

private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger( PerformanceTestcase.class.getName() );

@Parameter
public int noOfScripts;

@Before
public void generateLotsOfInstallerSkripts() throws IOException {
    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "generating {0} skripts", noOfScripts);
    Path baseVersion = getBaseVersionPath();
    generateSkripts( noOfScripts, baseVersion, BASE_SKRIPT_NAME );
}

@Test
public void testPerformance() throws IOException, SQLException {
    // this one does not scale well with increasing noOfScripts
    migrate();
}

private static final String SCHEMA_TABLE_NAME = "test_versions";

private static final String SKRIPT_NAME_FORMAT = "%s.%05d__test.sql";
private static final String SKRIPT_CONTENT = "select %05d from dual;";

private static final String FILESYSTEM = "filesystem:";

private static final String BASE_SKRIPT_NAME = "V00.00.00";
private static final String BASE_DIR = "/tmp/performanceTest";

private void migrate() throws SQLException {
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setDataSource( getDataSource() );
    flyway.setLocations( FILESYSTEM + BASE_DIR );
    flyway.setTable( SCHEMA_TABLE_NAME );
    flyway.setBaselineVersionAsString(BASE_SKRIPT_NAME.substring(1) );
    flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
    flyway.setValidateOnMigrate(false);

    flyway.migrate();
}

@Parameters(name="noOfScripts={0}")
public static Iterable<? extends Object> data() {
    List<Integer> retval = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for ( int i=0; i<16000; i+=1000 ) {
        if ( i>0 ) retval.add( Integer.valueOf(i) );
        retval.add( Integer.valueOf(i+100) );
    }
    return retval;
}

private Path getBaseDirPath() throws IOException {
    Path base = Paths.get(BASE_DIR);
    if ( !Files.exists(base) ) {
        Files.createDirectory(base);
    }
    return base;
}

private Path getBaseVersionPath() throws IOException {
    Path base = getBaseDirPath();
    Path baseVersion = base.resolve(BASE_SKRIPT_NAME);
    if ( !Files.exists(baseVersion) ) {
        Files.createDirectories(baseVersion);
    }
    return baseVersion;
}

private void generateSkripts( int numberOfSkripts, Path baseDir, String baseName ) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSkripts; i++) {
        Path file = baseDir.resolve( String.format(SKRIPT_NAME_FORMAT, baseName, i) );
        Files.write( file
                   , Arrays.asList( new String[] { String.format( SKRIPT_CONTENT, i ) } )
                   , StandardOpenOption.CREATE
                   , StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING
                   );
    }

}

private DataSource getDataSource() throws SQLException {
    OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
    ds.setURL(CONNECTION_URL);
    return ds;
}
}
```

**Update**

I just run the testcase with the current version 4.0.3 of flywayDB. It ran about half the time compared to 3.2.1, but the scaling problem still persists. Flyway is selecting the complete versions table per single migration step, which significantly slows down a migration when the version table is quite populated.

**Update again**

I've looked into the source-code of flywayDB version 4.0.3: In `org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate#migrate` the `MigrationInfoServiceImpl` is created and refreshed. This selects the full schema_versions-Table. But after that step only a single migration script is executed. I would expect migrating all pending scripts instead.

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1415) on this one at github.

Comment: Are the SQL-scripts stored in a table in the database or as files on a filesystem?

Comment: The SQL-scripts are files from filesystem.

Comment: Did you analyse the performance of each step in the process? I suspect that Oracle can read a table with 10000 records within the blink of an eye, I would not be so sure about a Java app and OS that have to index and read 10000 files on disk.

Comment: Yes, of course. A profiler gave the hint to the method with the calculation of the installation rank. It really seems to be a problem at client side. The database is at very low load.

Comment: OK. I don't think I can help you then, sorry :-) I understood your question as that you were looking at a database performance problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [issue](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1415) is fixed. Today I tested flyway version 4.1.2 and the performance problem is gone. Thanks for the great work at [boxfuse](http://www.flywaydb.org)!

Comment: They seem to be owned by RedGate now.